# Shimmercat setup template

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, webserver, shimmercat

I learn how to use Shimmercat \for Linux .
Using manual: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_0VdzHEISbo
And while I try to setup template (after unzipping the archive) - got the next issue:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-Lenovo-G505s:~/mywebproject2$ mv startbootstrap-creative-1.0.5 site files
mv: указанная цель «files» не является каталогом / target specified is not a directory
```

What can be the reason and how to fix it?
Thanx

Comment: Hi! You just want to do:  `mv startbootstrap-creative-1.0.5 sitefiles`, without the space. In the video, the right border of the terminal cuts the two words, but the purpose is stated in the caption: to shorten the original name and make it manegeable.

Comment: Thank you. the reason was much more obvious - I used the template name as in video, by my own was different

Answer (score 2):

`mv startbootstrap-creative-1.0.5 site files` means "move the file* `startbootstrap-creative-1.0.5` and the file `site` into the directory `files`, all files being in the current directory (`$PWD`)". If `files` is not a directory this will fail.

* A directory is a [special type of file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/37831/3645)

Comment: Please update the original question or create a new one.